# Pasar arreglo por ajax jquery a PHP post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente arreglo que quiero mandar por ajax jquery por post a php codeigniter

> var array = [];

```
(2) [Object, Object]
0
:
Object
Codigo
:
"11111"
Descripción
:
"caja"
Eliminar
:
" Eliminar"
Precio
:
"$46"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
Codigo
:
"22222"
Descripción
:
"lapiz"
Eliminar
:
" Eliminar"
Precio
:
"$222"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:


    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php print base_url();?>controlador/Guardar",
          data: array,//no se como mandar la data a php            
          success: function(objView){
          alert("volvio");
        }
});
```

de que forma lo tendría que recibir en php codeigniter ?

he intentado con este código pero me retorna un array null muchas gracias

```
public function Guardar(){


        $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['array']));
        echo var_dump($data);

    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Esta es la forma correcta de enviar un arreglo por ajax

```
var array = [1,2,3,4]; //array que deseo enviar

$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: ...,
          data: {'array': JSON.stringify(array)},//capturo array     
          success: function(data){

        }
});
```

> De esta forma de recibe en el backend por php

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['array']);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Hola! hasta ahi veo lo recibe bien pero como dar echo a un campo en especifico?

Comment: La variable $data es un array por lo tanto el campo lo tendrías que llamar así. <?php echo $data[3]; ?> Con esto llamas al número 4.

Answer (score -2):

Este es mi ejemplo

```
[html]
<form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="entrevista_rrhh">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Entrevista RRHH</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="examen_ortografia">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Examen de ortografía</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="entrevista_area">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Entrevista área</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="evaluaciones_tecnicas">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Evaluaciones técnicas</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="entrevista_coach">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Entrevista Coach</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="evaluacion_de_idioma">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Evaluación de idioma</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="evaluatest">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Evaluatest</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="en_proceso_de_oferta">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>En proceso de Oferta</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="solicitud_de_empleo">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Solicitud de empleo</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="estatusInput" name="estatusCandidato" value="lista_de_documentos">
                    <label><span><span></span></span>Lista de documentos</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="" class="button" id="estatusCandidatoSubmit">Actualizar estatus</a>
    </div>
    </form>


[jquery]
$('#estatusCandidatoSubmit').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var datos = {};
var campo ='';

$('.estatusInput').each(function(index){
  campo = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    datos[campo] = 1;
  }
  else{
    datos[campo] = 0;
  }
});
var datosArray = datos;
datosArray = {'datos': datosArray};
var data = $.param(datosArray);
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
  url: 'estatus.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
      alert('success');
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert('error');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Hola Ruben, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad, intenta añadir algo más de detalle y no sólo código: ¿qué es lo que hace tu ejemplo? ¿cuáles son las partes clave? ¿qué es lo que servirá de ayuda al usuario para resolver el problema de la pregunta? Te recomiendo que leas [answer] y que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y así ganar tu primera medalla).