# Concatenar segundo data Ajax jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Actualmente estoy enviando por `Ajax` un `Array`, pero necesito enviar otra data:

```
//data que necesito enviar
var ParamObjSend = {

    "id" :$("#id").val(), 

};

var array = [1,2,3,4];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php print base_url();?>Controller/Guardar",
    data: {"array": JSON.stringify(array), ParamObjSend}, //de esta forma sigue sin funcionar      
    success: function(objView){
        alert("entro");
    }
});
```

Al enviarlo no logro capturarlo con `PHP`:

```
public function Guardar () {    

    $dataPost = $this->input->post('id');//no llega

}
```

Comment: Javier, ya te respondí en tu otra pregunta que era la misma que está. Lo cual esta pregunta será cerrada como duplicada. E aquí la prueba: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/68999/14243

Comment: es distinta por que necesito pasar un data aparte del arreglo, no dentro del mismo arreglo

Comment: aunque sea distinta, el problema es el mismo

Comment: Si no la he puesto como resuelta es por que no funciono , la solución era otra tu no entendiste mi problema de todas formas gracias por responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Estabas cerca!, en `data` van todos los valores que debes enviar. Colocaré el ejemplo del `Ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php print base_url();?>Controller/Guardar",
    data: {
        "array"       : JSON.stringify(array), 
        "status"      : true, 
        "miotrovalor" : 122,
        ParamObjSend
    },
    success: function(objView){
        alert("entro");
    }
});
```

Comment: Que seria mitrovalor ?, tengo que colocar el id de esa forma ?

Comment: Editare el ajax de mi pregunta, sigo sin poder recibir el dato con php dede ajax

Comment: me funciono gracias !