# Cómo enviar un array de javascript por medio de ajax para que el archivo .php capturarlo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema. Tengo un array en una variable de javavscript, llamado "arrayCompleto" que contiene estos valores al hacer console.log:

```
array(4) {
  ["titulo"]=>
  string(28) "Curso de canvas y Javascript"
  ["cantidad"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["valorItem"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["idProducto"]=>
  string(3) "403"
}
```

Luego, quiero enviar el array por AJAX a un archivo PHP para que pueda capturar el array y poder utilizarlo. Hago lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({

     url:rutaOculta+"controladores/carrito.controlador.php",
     method:"POST",
     data: { 'arrayCompleto' : arrayCompleto },
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,

});
```

Y finalmente en el archivo carrito.controlador.php hago lo siguiente:

```
$arrayAjax = json_decode($_POST['arrayCompleto']);

var_dump($arrayCompleto);
```

Pero me arroja como resultado:

```
Notice: Undefined index: arrayCompleto in C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\controladores\carrito.controlador.php on line 76

NULL
```

Alguien sabe porque pasa esto? Gracias!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Pasar arreglo por ajax jquery a PHP post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68999/pasar-arreglo-por-ajax-jquery-a-php-post)

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa he visto esa pregunta pero no me funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Primero, deberías definir la cabecera `content-type` como `application/json; charset=utf-8` para indicar que el formato del cuerpo de la petición es`JSON`.

Segundo, para obtener los datos de una petición `POST` con formato `JSON`:

```
# Obtener el cuerpo de la petición como una cadena
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

# Convertir la cadena JSON a un objeto PHP
$peticion = json_decode($json)
```

El formato `JSON` no puede ser leido con `$_POST` porque es un archivo de texto y no un arreglo asociativo.

Comment: Gracias! Intentaré a lo largo del día hacer eso que me dices, y te comentaré qué tal me fue